# Remove values from nested dictionary

Tags: python

I've got a nested dictionary:

```
{'a': {'m': 1, 'n': 0}, 'b': {'m': 0, 'x': 1}}
```

is there a simple way of removing all the nested zero values so the dictionary becomes:

```
{'a': {'m': 1}, 'b': {'x': 1}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> d = {'a': {'m': 1, 'n': 0}, 'b': {'m': 0, 'x': 1}}
>>> {key: {k:v for k,v in d[key].items() if v != 0} for key in d}
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'m': 1}, 'b': {'x': 1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach, that modifies the dictionary in-place:

```
d = {'a': {'m': 1, 'n': 0}, 'b': {'m': 0, 'x': 1}}

for dd in d.values():
    for k, v in list(dd.items()):
        if v == 0:
            dd.pop(k)

print(d)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': {'m': 1}, 'b': {'x': 1}}
```

Comment: Did it with dictionary comprehension and published the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
d = {'a': {'m': 1, 'n': 0}, 'b': {'m': 0, 'x': 1}}
result = {k: {k1: v1 for k1, v1 in v.items() if v1 != 0} for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

One-line solution:

```
d = {'a': {'m': 1, 'n': 0}, 'b': {'m': 0, 'x': 1}}

d_new = {k: {inner_k: inner_v for inner_k, inner_v in v.items() if inner_v != 0} for k, v in d.items()}

print(d_new)  # Prints: {'a': {'m': 1}, 'b': {'x': 1}}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can even try to convert your nested dict to flat and then look for value zero

Code:

```
[d[k[0]].pop(k[-1]) for k,v in pd.json_normalize(d).to_dict(orient='records')[0].items() if v==0]
d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_1 = {'a': {'m': 1, 'n': 0}, 'b': {'m': 0, 'x': 1}}
new_dict_1={}
for key in dict_1.keys():
    for v,k in zip(dict_1[key].values(),dict_1[key].keys()):
        if v != 0 :
            new_dict_1[key] = {k:v}
            
new_dict_1
```